# Redirect loops on cloudflare

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare to manage my domain.
Considering the following:

1. type = A, name = [mydomain].me, value = xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, TTL = automatic
2. type = A, name = www, value = xx.xx.xx.xx.xx, TTL = automatic

   With the following page RULE:
3. https://[mydomain].me -> (301) http://[mydomain].me

The site is wordpress based and each configuration (wp-config, DB or otherwise) is stating [mydomain].me.

**Still**, while both chrome and safari on mobile works perfectly ok, safari (MAC) is saying too many redirects.

Any ideas? how can I debug the redirect that is happening? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting away from HTTPS isn't a great idea; but you should make sure that you have no conflicting rules in your .htaccess file and that HSTS (strict transport security) is turned off in CloudFlare. HSTS uses aggressive caching, [there are instructions on how to clear this here](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers).

[Someone had some luck](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5884595?start=15&tstart=0) by deleting in /library/Cookies all files with "safari" in its name and the "HSTS.plist". Make sure you're happy deleting the relevent cache files before you do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "http" protocol is used in wordpress for the site's base url.